# If $\lim _{x \to 0}\: f(x) = L,$ then $\lim _{t \to \infty} \:f(\frac {1}{t} )= L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim _{x \to 0}\: f(x) = L,$ then $\lim _{t \to \infty} \:f(\frac {1}{t} )= L$   with $x=\frac{1}{t}$

Let $ \epsilon\:>\:0$ be given.

Since $\: \lim_{x\to a}\:f(x)=L \:\:  \exists \: \delta \:>\:0$ such that when

$0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

Let $ x = \frac{1}{t}$. Then $|f(\frac{1}{t})-L|<\epsilon$ for  $0<\frac{1}{t}<\delta$ or $t > \frac{1}{\delta}$.

Thus if we let $M> \frac{1}{\delta}$ with $t\geq M$ then $|f(\frac{1}{t})-L|<\epsilon$.

Is this correct?

And why is the converse not true?

Comment: If $t\to+\infty$ then $\frac 1t\to 0^+$ and if $t\to-\infty$ then $\frac 1t\to 0^-$. You cannot really write $t\to\infty$ without a sign. It is possible to write $|t|\to+\infty$ though to take care of both cases. Yet the wording of your question asks only for implication so it is ok. If you would want equivalence, you would need to keep absolute values (i.e. $|x|<\delta$ then $\frac 1{|t|}<\delta$)

Comment: @zwim Infinity equals +Infinity is generally considered to be true IMO.